# reduce height of navbar in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to reduce the size of the navbar in bootstrap. I have spent a lot of time on this and have tried doing the following things in my css file:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {padding-top:5px !important; padding-bottom:5px !important;}
.navbar {min-height:32px !important}
```

also:

```
.tnav .navbar .container { height: 28px; }
```

non of these changes made any difference :(

I have added my html and current CSS file and i would appreciate any help i can get.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Fonts -->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {!! Form::image('img/logo.gif', 'logo', 
                array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ))
                !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                {!! Form::image('img/social_links.gif', 'logo', 
                array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ))
                !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
<div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            </div>      
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="carousel-fuudey" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-fuudey" data-slide-to="0" calss="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-fuudey" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-fuudey" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/banner.gif" alt="banner" />
                        </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/banner.gif" alt="banner" />
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/banner.gif" alt="banner" />
                        </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>login</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                       <p>menu</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>contact</p>
            </div>  
            </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {!! Form::image('img/gal-pic.gif', 'gallery',
                array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ))
                !!} 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {!! Form::image('img/left.gif', 'gallery',
                array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ))
                !!} 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {!! Form::image('img/middle.gif', 'gallery',
                array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ))
                !!} 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {!! Form::image('img/right.gif', 'gallery',
                array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ))
                !!} 
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">

        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>


</div>
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #4f0100;
  border-color: #4f0100;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #4f0100;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
  background-color: #4f0100;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .divider {
 background-color: #4f0100;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
  background-color: #4f0100;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
  background-color: #4f0100;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #4f0100;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #4f0100;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ecdbff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ecdbff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
     color: #ecdbff;
    background-color: #4f0100;
  }
}
```

Comment: need more explanation , how do you want to reduce navbar size ? can you add your codes in jsfiddle.net

Comment: sorry i meant reduce the height

Comment: can't seem to get jsfiddle to work

Comment: http://prntscr.com/675en3 bootstrap have minheight in .navbar changing that may help , i am not sure thou because i dont know your problem exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, looking at your code I noticed in your html that you are not including a stylesheet named bootstrap? So I am assuming that one of the two css files is the bootstrap and by the labeling common.css looks to be it. If this is the case reverse the order of the css files. You need to include the bootstrap.css (common.css?) file before trying to override any css styles.

```
.navbar {min-height:32px !important}
```

should work.

Try adding your own class

```
.navClass { height:32px !important; min-height:32px !important; }
```

If none of that works you can always go to the bootstrap website and edit the css to your liking and just change the navbar styles. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar <-- link to navbar styles just change that height property then download the package. Or if you know less you can just change the less files yourself and compile them again with whatever changes you want.

Comment: the problem is the size set on the child elements

Comment: What child elements? All he has in there is more divs.

Comment: I think the problem is the order of the css files anyways

Comment: Well yeah, the posted code doesn't actually show the contents of the navbar, which it should.

Comment: So in your answer you are targeting elements that don't exist... given the code.

Comment: My answer is showing how to "reduce height of navbar in bootstrap 3" as asked.

Comment: You say the problem is the child elements but if I use the code I provided in your bootply, it seems to work. I wonder why?

Comment: Because I fixed it in the bootply. The bootply is a functioning example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71279/discussion-between-ted-and-floor).

Comment: Refer to discussion moved to chat.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adjust a couple items CSS:

[**See this bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/xk8VFj6YBU)

Assuming a height of 32px, add these overrides:

```
.navbar{
    min-height:32px;
}

.navbar-brand{
    height:32px;
    padding:5px 15px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

Just be sure they are added after the default bootstrap css file

HTH

-Ted